# Is it possible to apply colon operator on an expression in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

It's very convenient if it was possible to use colon operator on a expression. Well to my knowledge, it's not possible. For example when I want to calculate the differences between two matrices, I have to do it in two lines.

```
diff = (a - b);
err = sum(abs(diff(:)));
```

instead of

```
diff = sum(abs((a-b)(:)));
```

Is there anyway around it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get around syntax limitations with anonymous helper functions.  EG

```
oneD = @(x)x(:);
diff = sum(abs(oneD(a-b))));
```

Still takes two lines though.

Comment: I like your idea. I wish you could name oneD colon. It might conflict with the colon operator!

Comment: You are right.  Using the name `colon` would cause you no end of trouble.

Comment: So you consider it a valid answer to replace a two-line solution with another two-line solution, and in addition replace the simple colon operator with an anonymous solution! "Things should be made as simple as possible, but not any simpler."

Answer (score 3):

Two options:

```
err = sum(abs(a(:)-b(:)));
```

or

```
err = sum(abs(reshape(a-b,[],1)));
```

Answer (score 1):

In this particular case, you could do `sum(abs(a(:)-b(:)))`, but in general Matlab doesn't support that sort of nested indices.