# MATLAB nesting multiple input functions

Tags: matlab

Given a multiple-input MATLAB function

```
out=f(in1, in2)
```

I would like to write a second function g which generates the inputs for f, e.g.

```
[in1, in2]=g(in)
```

so that I can call something like:

```
out=f(g(in))
```

I have tried writing g as a single output function that stores `in1` and `in2` in a cell array so that I can feed the output of g to f using the colon operator:

```
in_c=g(in);
out=f(in_c{:})
```

but I was looking for a one-line solution, which seems not possible to achieve this way as I read in [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9337713/is-it-possible-to-apply-colon-operator-on-an-expression-in-matlab)

Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: This is not possible in Matlab. The best you could do is to have `f` take a cell array as input, and `g` return a cell array as output.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Matlab --- splice vector into arguments for function call](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11461963/matlab-splice-vector-into-arguments-for-function-call)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[As discussed recently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11461963/matlab-splice-vector-into-arguments-for-function-call/11462984#11462984), this is not possible in Matlab.

However, if you do not want to re-write your function `g(x,y)` to return a cell array, you can still do everything in two lines:

```
[in4f{1}, in4f{2}] = g(in);
out = f(in4f{:});
```

As an aside: Unless you're really hurting for memory, it doesn't make a lot of sense to try and force one-line statements everywhere by avoiding temporary variables. Sure, you can make your code look like CrazyPerl, but in the long run, you'll be glad for the added readability.

Comment: Generally you don't save on memory either as the temporaries are still created implicitly.